# What is the cleanest way to get the sum of numbers in a collection/list in Dart?

Tags: iteration, dart

I don't like using an indexed array for no reason other than I think it looks ugly. Is there a clean way to sum with an anonymous function? Is it possible to do it without using any outside variables?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Dart iterables now have a reduce function (https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1649), so you can do a sum pithily without defining your own fold function:

```
var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: This fails if the list is empty. `.fold()` handles that case.

Comment: getting error `Uncaught Error: Bad state: No element` if `List` is empty. I have checked `List.length` before `var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b);` statement and it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Had an issue when working with custom objects e.g. Object.amount

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please consider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68603277/8539278

Comment: You can use this to handle empty list too: [1, 2, 3].fold(0, (e, t) => e + t);

Comment: You can use fold to handle empty list too: [1, 2, 3].fold(0, (e, t) => e + t);

Answer (score 139):

```dart
int sum = [1, 2, 3].fold(0, (previous, current) => previous + current);
```

or with shorter variable names to make it take up less room:

```dart
int sum = [1, 2, 3].fold(0, (p, c) => p + c);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is more generalizable to work on empty lists.

Comment: I prefer this answer.. why does reduce even exist?!
Me: I want `.fold`
Mom: We already have `.fold` at home
`.fold` at home: `.reduce`

Answer (score 84):

This is a very old question but

### **In 2022 there is actually a built-in package**.

Just import

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

and call the `.sum` extension method on the `Iterable`.

**FULL EXAMPLE**

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  final list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  final sum = list.sum;
  print(sum); // prints 10
}
```

If the list is empty, `.sum` returns `0`.

You might also be interested in `list.average`...

Comment: Is it possible to use this method to add all the numbers up to a certain index in the list?

Comment: Sure, you can write `list.sublist(0,3).sum`, which sums up from index 0 until exluding index 3

Comment: Also, every Iterable has a `.take(int count)` method, letting you omit the lower "0" boundary and creating a lazy iterator instead of a list (which might be more performant if you don't need all items as you do with the "sum" getter)

Answer (score 29):

I still think this is cleaner and easier to understand for this particular problem.

```
num sum = 0;
[1, 2, 3].forEach((num e){sum += e;});
print(sum);
```

or

```
num sum = 0;
for (num e in [1,2,3]) {
  sum += e;
}
```

Comment: Logic like this should be engraved into the being of any programmer. Unfortunately todays copy paste programmers are busy looking for helper methods/packages rather than just going back to the basics. Congrats & thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 10):

There is not a clean way to do it using the core libraries as they are now, but if you roll your own **foldLeft** then there is

```
main() {
  var sum = foldLeft([1,2,3], 0, (val, entry) => val + entry);
  print(sum);
}

Dynamic foldLeft(Collection collection, Dynamic val, func) {
  collection.forEach((entry) => val = func(val, entry));
  return val;
}
```

I talked to the Dart team about adding **foldLeft** to the core collections and I hope it will be there soon.

Comment: This could be addressed by adding an inject function to the collection interface like in Ruby.

Comment: That's some very pretty code there, Lars. Not only was it what I was looking for, now I understand folding.

Comment: You can certainly do it with an anonymous function, with or without any library code to do it, just by inlining the code in foldLeft above. And you're pretty much always going to need a variable, unless you're excessively clever with recursion. Alternatively, you can also just do it with a for(var each in...) rather than forEach, and apply the function in the body of the for loop. Either works.

Comment: Note that there are already some external libraries for working with collections -- some of them were mentioned in this thread: http://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/group/misc/browse_thread/thread/0628027441ad1ac8/329810f9fa00a866 Also the collections library is undergoind severe changes currently, I hope that sum (or at least fold/reduce) is coming right into it.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Dart 2.6 you can use extensions to define a utility method on the List. This works for numbers (example 1) but also for generic objects (example 2).

```
extension ListUtils<T> on List<T> {
  num sumBy(num f(T element)) {
    num sum = 0;
    for(var item in this) {
      sum += f(item);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Example 1 (sum all the numbers in the list):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var sum = numbers.sumBy((number) => number);
```

Example 2 (sum all the Point.x fields):

```
var points = [Point(1, 2), Point(3, 4)];
var sum = points.sumBy((point) => point.x);
```

Comment: hi, are extension methods ready yet?  I just tried to enable them by adding the experiments flag (dart 2.6.1) but then lost intellisense and received a dart analyser exception in IntelliJ.  Any ideas?

Comment: @atreeon I don't remember adding any flag but remember to update your Flutter, Dart plugins to latest versions and also double check that you're actually using at least version 2.6.0. Also the extension class (ListUtils in this case) needs to be imported in the file where you're trying to use it.

Comment: I was using it in a stand alone Dart app, I've just upgraded to the latest Flutter and it says I have 2.5 (I think there are different version for the flutter install to what is run on the comman line)...so, the latest version of Flutter uses 2.5???  I am so confused!

Comment: I got it working!!  These extension methods are much nice

Answer (score 5):

I'd just like to add some small detail to @tmaihoff's answer (about using the [collection.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package):

The `sum` getter he talks about only works for iterables of `num` values, like `List<int>` or `Set<double>`.

If you have a list of other object types that represent values (like `Money`, `Decimal`, `Rational`, or any others) you must map it to numbers. For example, to count the number of chars in a list of strings you can do:

```
// Returns 15.
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde'].map((e) => e.length).sum;
```

As of 2022, another way of doing it, is using the `sumBy()` method of the [fast_immutable_collections](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections) package:

```
// Returns 15.
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde'].sumBy((e) => e.length), 15);
```

Note: I'm the package author.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to create this function in any common utility file.

`T sum<T extends num>(T lhs, T rhs) => lhs + rhs;`

int, double, float extends num class so you can use that function to sum any numbers.

e.g.,

```
List<int> a = [1,2,3];
int result = a.reduce(sum);
print(result); // result will be 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Herewith sharing my Approach:

```
void main() {
  int value = sumTwo([1, 4, 3, 43]);
  print(value);
}

int sumTwo(List < int > numbers) {
  int sum = 0;

  for (var i in numbers) {
    sum = sum + i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If when using fold gives a `double` TypeError, you can use reduce:

```
var sum = [0.0, 4.5, 6.9].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on doing a number of mathematical operations on your list, it may be helpful to create another list type that includes .sum() and other operations by extending ListBase. Parts of this are [inspired by this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839714/3050664) with [performance tweaks from this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16247102/3050664).

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:core';

class Vector<num> extends ListBase<num> {
  
  List<num> _list;
  Vector() : _list = new List<num>();
  Vector.fromList(List<num> lst): _list = lst;
  
  void set length(int l) {
    this._list.length=l;
  }

  int get length => _list.length;
  
  num operator [](int index) => _list[index];

  void operator []=(int index, num value) {
    _list[index]=value;
  }
  // Though not strictly necessary, for performance reasons
  // you should implement add and addAll.

  void add(num value) => _list.add(value);

  void addAll(Iterable<num> all) => _list.addAll(all);
  
  num sum() => _list.fold(0.0, (a, b) => a + b) as num;
  /// add additional vector functions here like min, max, mean, factorial, normalize etc

}
```

And use it like so:

```
Vector vec1 = Vector();
vec1.add(1); 
print(vec1); // => [1]
vec1.addAll([2,3,4,5]); 
print(vec1); // => [1,2,3,4,5]
print(vec1.sum().toString()); // => 15
Vector vec = Vector.fromList([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]); // works for double too.
print(vec.sum().toString()); // => 15
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that has worked cleanly for me is:

```
var total => [1,2,3,4].fold(0, (e, t) => e + t); // result 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to find the sum of all dart list elements,

Method 1: Using a loop :
This is the most commonly used method. Iterate through the list using a loop and add all elements of the list to a final sum variable. We are using one for loop here :

```
main(List<String> args) {
  var sum = 0;
  var given_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  for (var i = 0; i < given_list.length; i++) {
    sum += given_list[i];
  }

  print("Sum : ${sum}");
}
```

Method 2: Using forEach :
forEach is another way to iterate through a list. We can also use this method to find out the total sum of all values in a dart list. It is similar to the above method. The only difference is that we don’t have to initialize another variable i and list.length is not required.

```
main(List<String> args) {
  var sum = 0;
  var given_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  given_list.forEach((e) => sum += e);

  print("Sum : ${sum}");
}
```

Method 3: Using reduce :
reduce method combines all elements of a list iteratively to one single value using a given function. We can use this method to find out the sum of all elements as like below :

```
main(List<String> args) {
  var given_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  var sum = given_list.reduce((value, element) => value + element);

  print("Sum : ${sum}");
}
```

Method 4: Using fold :
fold() is similar to reduce. It combines all elements of a list iteratively to one single value using a function. It takes one initial value and calculates the final value based on the previous value.

```
main(List<String> args) {
  var sum = 0;
  var given_list = [1,2,3,4,5];

  sum = given_list.fold(0, (previous, current) => previous + current);

  print("Sum : ${sum}");
}
```

for more details:https://www.codevscolor.com/dart-find-sum-list-elements

Answer (score -1):

```dart
extension DoubleArithmeticExtensions on Iterable<double> {
  double get sum => length == 0 ? 0 : reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

extension IntArithmeticExtensions on Iterable<int> {
  int get sum => length == 0 ? 0 :  reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Usage:

```dart
final actual = lineChart.data.lineBarsData[0].spots.map((s) => s.x).sum;
```