# How do I extend a List in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to create a more specialized list in dart. I can't directly extend [List](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html). What are my options?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a ListBase class in dart:collection. If you extend this class, you only need to implement:

- `get length`
- `set length`
- `[]=`
- `[]`

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class FancyList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  List innerList = new List();

  int get length => innerList.length;

  void set length(int length) {
    innerList.length = length;
  }

  void operator[]=(int index, E value) {
    innerList[index] = value;
  }

  E operator [](int index) => innerList[index];

  // Though not strictly necessary, for performance reasons
  // you should implement add and addAll.

  void add(E value) => innerList.add(value);

  void addAll(Iterable<E> all) => innerList.addAll(all);
}

void main() {
  var list = new FancyList();

  list.addAll([1,2,3]);

  print(list.length);
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asked about the options, could you clarify what else you can do?

Comment: @amouravski I'd love to know :)

Comment: I guess the other two options would be to implement the List interface, or use List as a mixin.

Comment: For performance one should usually also override (and delegate) at least `add` and `addAll`. These are heavily used methods that are much more efficient when they don't go through `length` and `[]`. See http://dartbug.com/12652.

Comment: Just for curiosity. <E> would mean any kind of object? If I want to implement a List witch only accepts <Apple>, should I substitute all <E>'s for <Apple>?

Comment: Yes, use `class AppleList extends ListBase<Apple>{}` and replace all `E` by `Apple`.

Comment: So, how to define list of lists with this approach, I could not define `FancyList [FancyLists]' :(

Comment: Another point, is there a way to convert my `List` to `FancyList`, something I can develop like `.toFancyList` or so!

Answer (score 44):

To make a class implement [List](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html) there are several ways :

- Extending [ListBase](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/ListBase.html) and implementing [`length`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length), [`operator[]`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#[]), [`operator[]=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#[]=) and [`length=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length=) :

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class MyCustomList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  final List<E> l = [];
  MyCustomList();

  void set length(int newLength) { l.length = newLength; }
  int get length => l.length;
  E operator [](int index) => l[index];
  void operator []=(int index, E value) { l[index] = value; }

  // your custom methods
}
```

- Mixin [ListMixin](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/ListMixin.html) and implementing [`length`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length), [`operator[]`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#[]), [`operator[]=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#[]=) and [`length=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length=) :

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class MyCustomList<E> extends Base with ListMixin<E> {
  final List<E> l = [];
  MyCustomList();

  void set length(int newLength) { l.length = newLength; }
  int get length => l.length;
  E operator [](int index) => l[index];
  void operator []=(int index, E value) { l[index] = value; }

  // your custom methods
}
```

- Delegating to an other `List` with [`DelegatingList`](http://google.github.io/quiver-dart/docs/quiver.collection/DelegatingList.html) from the [quiver package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver):

```dart
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

class MyCustomList<E> extends DelegatingList<E> {
  final List<E> _l = [];

  List<E> get delegate => _l;

  // your custom methods
}
```

- Delegating to an other `List` with [`DelegatingList`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/DelegatingList-class.html) from the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection):

```dart
import 'package:collection/wrappers.dart';

class MyCustomList<E> extends DelegatingList<E> {
  final List<E> _l;

  MyCustomList() : this._(<E>[]);
  MyCustomList._(l) :
    _l = l,
    super(l);

  // your custom methods
}
```

Depending on your code each of those options has their advantages. If you wrap/delegate an existing list you should use the last option. Otherwise, use one of the two first options depending on your type hierarchy (mixin allowing to extend another Object).

Comment: You can also use DelegatingList from package:collection/wrappers.dart in a similar way to the one from quiver.

Comment: I'm trying the second option, but getting an error the IDE under the `Base` telling `Minin can apply only for classes | undefined class Base`!

Comment: Using the first approach, how to define list of lists with this approach, I could not define `MyCustomList [MyCustomList]' :(

Comment: Another point, is there a way to convert my `List` to `MyCustomList`, something I can develop like `.MyCustomList` or so!

Comment: What is the best way to do this if I essentially just need a 'typedef', e.g. define class Grid to get rid of the List<List<int>> definition. Is it possible to skip redefining the getters and setters and delegate to super?

Comment: `.add()` does not work with ListBase.. There is a comment in the mixin saying it does not, and I just tried your code in dartpad and indeed add does not work

Answer (score 24):

A new way of extending classes was [introduced with Dart 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751).
You can now create an `extension` of `List` like this:

```dart
extension MyCustomList<T> on List<T> {
  // Any methods you want can be added here.
}
```

The methods you add [can be used **implicitly**](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.6/static-extension-members/feature-specification.md#implicit-extension-member-invocation), i.e. you can just use them on any `List` when you have your `extension` imported.
Here is an [example from the feature specification](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.6/static-extension-members/feature-specification.md#implicit-extension-member-invocation):

```dart
extension MyFancyList<T> on List<T> {
  int get doubleLength => this.length * 2;
  List<T> operator-() => this.reversed.toList();
  List<List<T>> split(int at) => 
      <List<T>>[this.sublist(0, at), this.sublist(at)];
  List<T> mapToList<R>(R Function(T) convert) => this.map(convert).toList();
}
```

You can use these new members on any `List`, e.g. like this:

```dart
const list = <String>['some', 'elements'];

list.doubleLength; // Evaluates to 4.
```

Answer (score 9):

The answers to this are pretty outdated, and I'm in the process of doing this for my own project, so I thought I'd help some people out by posting a really clean answer that doesn't involve any overriding or implementing of things.

The [quiver](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) package has an extendable List class called [DelegatingList](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/DelegatingList-class.html) that makes extending a list trivial.

```
class FruitList extends DelegatingList<Fruit> {
    final List<Fruit> _fruits = [];

    List<Fruit> get delegate => _fruits;

    // custom methods
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone who comes across this question like I did!

Comment: This worked for me, however `DelegatingList` also appears to be available in `package:collection` which I already had in my project, so I didn't need the `quiver` dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the answer above, you can create an immutable list like this:

```
class ImmutableList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  late final List<E> innerList;

  ImmutableList(Iterable<E> items) {
    innerList = List<E>.unmodifiable(items);
  }

  @override
  int get length => innerList.length;

  @override
  set length(int length) {
    innerList.length = length;
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, E value) {
    innerList[index] = value;
  }

  @override
  E operator [](int index) => innerList[index];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    //list is your given List and iterable is any object in dart that can be iterated
    list.addAll(Iterable)
```