# Extending base List class with extra functionality in Dart language

Tags: class, inheritance, dart, extend

This question is about Dart language.
I want to have a class which is just a List but with some extra functionality.

For example I have a class named Model:

```
class Model{
  String name;
  int type;
  Model(this.name, this.type);
}
```

I know that Model's type could take only four values: from 0 to 3.
And I want to have a method, which can give me a List of Models of specified type, e.g. `List<Model> modelCollection.getByType(int type);`.
I plan to to have four 'hidden' Lists of the Models (grouped by type) in that class.
Thus I need to override addition and removal of List elements to make that hidden lists being up to date.

How can I realize this as easy as possible?

P.S. I know this is quite simple, but I'm poorly familiar with Object inheritance and can't find proper examples.
P.P.S. I've also checked this but don't know is it outdated or not and didn't catch the idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extend a List in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247045/how-do-i-extend-a-list-in-dart)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make a class implement [List](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html) there are several ways :

- Extending [ListBase](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/ListBase.html) and implementing [`length`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length), [`operator[]`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#%5b%5d), [`operator[]=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#%5b%5d=) and [`length=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length=) :

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class MyCustomList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  final List<E> l = [];
  MyCustomList();

  void set length(int newLength) { l.length = newLength; }
  int get length => l.length;
  E operator [](int index) => l[index];
  void operator []=(int index, E value) { l[index] = value; }

  // your custom methods
}
```

- Mixin [ListMixin](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/ListMixin.html) and implementing [`length`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length), [`operator[]`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#%5b%5d), [`operator[]=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#%5b%5d=) and [`length=`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#length=) :

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class MyCustomList<E> extends Base with ListMixin<E> {
  final List<E> l = [];
  MyCustomList();

  void set length(int newLength) { l.length = newLength; }
  int get length => l.length;
  E operator [](int index) => l[index];
  void operator []=(int index, E value) { l[index] = value; }

  // your custom methods
}
```

- Delegating to an other `List` with [`DelegatingList`](http://google.github.io/quiver-dart/docs/quiver.collection/DelegatingList.html) from the [quiver package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver):

```dart
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

class MyCustomList<E> extends DelegatingList<E> {
  final List<E> _l = [];

  List<E> get delegate => _l;

  // your custom methods
}
```

Depending on your code each of those options have their advantages. If you wrap/delegate an existing list you should use the last option. Otherwise use one of the two first options depending on your type hierarchy (mixin allowing to extend an other Object).

Comment: Thank you, I'try the first one!

Answer (score 2):

A basic approach is to extend an Object with [IterableMixin](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/IterableMixin.html). It also seems that you don't even need to override the "length" getter or let's say all methods that the IterableMixin already provides.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';    

class Model {
   String name;
   int type;

   Model(this.name, this.type) {
   }
}

class ModelCollection extends Object with IterableMixin {

   List<Model> _models;
   Iterator get iterator => _models.iterator;

   ModelCollection() {
      this._models = new List<Model>();
   }

   //get one or the first type
   Model elementByType(int type) {

     for (Model model in _models) {
       if (model.type == type) {
          return model;
       }
     }       
   }

   //get all of the same type
   List<Model> elementsByType(int type) {

      List<Model> newModel = new List<Model>();

      for (Model model in _models) {
         if (model.type == type) {
            newModel.add(model);
         }
      }
      return newModel;       
   }

   add(Model model) {
      this._models.add(model);
   }
}
```

Excuse my strong static typing.

Comment: This approach seems mostly fits to my needs. I'll try both and share my final approach.

Comment: I like this answer better. More detail and I'm fond of strong static typing :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in quiver.dart's Multimap. It behaves like a Map that allows multiple values per key.

Here's the code on github: https://github.com/google/quiver-dart/blob/master/lib/src/collection/multimap.dart#L20

It's on pub simply as quiver. We'll be hosting the dartdocs somewhere soon.

Comment: In my case I need to extend exactly List class, because Web UI template iterations works great with Lists, but some kind tricky with Maps.

Comment: Maps, and Multimap too, have a `values` property that you can iterate over, so `<template iterate="{{ v in map.values }}">` will work.

Comment: Oh! Good news! Thanks!

Comment: Meanwhile I've found something [interesting](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_collection/ListMixin.html)