# How do I create a type alias

Tags: types, dart

How do I give a new name to already existing type?

Let's say I want to give to a `List<String>` the name `Directives` and then be able to say `directives = new Directives()`.

Comment: you don't, you cannot instantiate one type to another

Comment: @MPatel You misunderstood me. I want to do a C++ style typedef. That should be somehow possible, yes? I can always embed the List<String> in a new Directives class, but then exporting all the methods on the List is a lot of work…

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247045/how-do-i-extend-a-list-in-dart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459181/extending-base-list-class-with-extra-functionality-in-dart-language

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/generic-function-type-alias.md

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is possible now via an empty mixin

```
mixin ToAlias{}

class Stuff<T> {
  T value;
  Stuff(this.value);
}

class StuffInt = Stuff<int> with ToAlias;

main() {
  var stuffInt = StuffInt(3);
}
```

### EDIT 2.13

It looks likely that unreleased 2.13 will contain proper type aliasing without the need of a mixin.

```
typedef IntList = List<int>;
IntList il = [1,2,3];
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65#issuecomment-809900008
https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-12-499a6e689c87

Comment: is creating type alias an intended usage of mixin?

Comment: What would it look like to use this to answer the OP's question? Is it possible with this mixin pattern? Something like `Directives = List<Directive>`

Comment: It seems like you can only alias classes that you have defined yourself but you can use generics on them as in the example.

Comment: comming from Kotlin that looks like a wrapper over the type you want to make the alias on

Answer (score 11):

You can't define alias. For your case you can use [DelegatingList from quiver](http://google.github.io/quiver-dart/docs/quiver.collection/DelegatingList.html) to define `Directives` :

```dart
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

class Directives extends DelegatingList<String> {
  final List<String> delegate = [];
}
```

Comment: Strange. I would have thought that the Dart people would encourage giving names to data structures. There is a typedef keyword in Dart but that works only for function signatures. Thanks for your answer.