# Dart type aliases

Tags: dart

I like to use the newtype pattern for encapsulating strings or other too common data types.
Is there a way I can do this in dart? 
I found the **typedef** but apparently this is only for method callbacks.

Example type alias in typescript:

```js
type FileId = string;
```

Example newtype in rust:

```rust
struct FileId(String);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a type alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755337/how-do-i-create-a-type-alias)

Comment: Properly also related to: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/115