# In Flutter, how to transform a list of items into a Table widget using the stream API?

Tags: functional-programming, stream, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In a flutter app, I have a `List` of 25 items (for example `int` numbers) which I want to be displayed in a table of 5 rows & 5 columns. I want to use the stream API (`map`, `take`, etc.) to build each item using its own index (like in `ListView.builder`).

I imagine something like:
`Table(children: List.generate(25, (i) => i).map((i) => MyTableCell(i)).toList().take(5, into(TableRow())))` but of course this won't do...

I really don't want to use `for` loops for that purpose . Any ideas?

I hope that I explained myself well. I'll add details if needed. Thank you.

Comment: What about using `take` and `skip` ?

Comment: I couldn't figure a way that works for me. A specific example will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using a `GridView` would be easiest. If your really want to use a `Table`, I guess the challenge is dividing your `List<int>` of 25 items into a `List<List<int>>` so that you can use it as `children` for the `Table`?

I'd suggest:

```
yourList.fold([[]], (list, x) {    
  return list.last.length == 5 ? (list..add([x])) : (list..last.add(x));
});
```

(Solution shamelessly copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274034/12441019) - because it's a great one :-)).

However, some might say that a `for` loop doing the same thing would be more common and thus easier to read for many... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A GridView takes a cross-axis count, and a stream of items.  No math required.

Comment: Of course GridView will be awesome, but then I saw https://youtu.be/_lbE0wsVZSw which states that Table is preferred over GridView when you want a non-scrollable widget.