# TypeError while attempting to sort a list of custom objects

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart and tried to get a class to implement `List` using the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16247045), and tried to sort a list of these objects using the docs [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/sort.html). I deleted most of my code in an effort to post a MWE:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class Transaction<E> extends ListBase<E>{
    DateTime when;
    Transaction(this.when);
    List innerList = new List();
    int get length => innerList.length;
    void set length(int length){
        innerList.length = length;
    }
    void operator[]=(int index, E value){
        innerList[index] = value;
    }
    E operator [](int index) => innerList[index];
    void add(E value) => innerList.add(value);
    void addAll(Iterable<E> all) => innerList.addAll(all);
}

class Forecaster{
    var transactions;
    Forecaster(){
        this.transactions = new List<dynamic>();
    }
    void tabulate(){
        transactions.sort((a,b) => a.when.compareTo(b.when)); //problem line?
        for(var d in transactions){
            d.asMap().forEach((index,content){
                int len = content.toStringAsFixed(2).length;
            });
        }
    }
    void forecast(var forWhen){
        var first = new Transaction(DateTime.now());
        first.addAll([5,9]);
        transactions.add(first);
    }
}

void main(){
    Forecaster myTest = new Forecaster();
    var dub = myTest;
    dub..forecast(DateTime.now())
       ..tabulate();
}
```

Running with the problem line results in an exception (Uncaught exception: TypeError: Closure 'Forecaster_tabulate_closure': type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => int') I don't understand. If I comment out the problem line, the `TypeError` goes away. Is the `TypeError` because I did something wrong when defining `Transaction`? I'm attempting this with [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to Dart too, so my explanation might not be 100% on the money, but I believe, yes, the main issue is the type assignment of `transactions`. I think because you initialize it as a var, it is having trouble deducing the type of `a.when`, which is means it also doesn't know the type of `a.when.compareTo()`, and assumes `dynamic`.  You are feeding the output of `compareTo` into `List.sort()` which is expecting an `int` from the anonymous function. Thus the error that it wanted an `int` but got `dynamic`.

The easiest way to address this is to initialize transactions with a more explicit type rather than as var:

```dart
List<Transaction> transactions;
Forecaster(){
    this.transactions = new List<Transaction>();
}
```

Also, to confirm that it is an issue with it not being able to infer the return type of compareTo, I tried leaving your code as-is, but explicitly casting the result as int, and that also worked:

```dart
transactions.sort((a,b){
    return (a.when.compareTo(b.when) as int);
});
```

Note: code like the above and using lots of dynamics and vars is in general not great practice with Dart - you lose a lot of the benefits of having a typed language. You might also notice that when you type in an IDE, you don't get methods auto-suggested when you do stuff like this - for example, until I changed `transactions` to an explicit type of list, typing `a.when` did not trigger autocomplete, and my IDE thought the type was `dynamic`, not `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the types. The code:

```
var transactions;
Forecaster(){
    this.transactions = new List<dynamic>();
}
void tabulate(){
    transactions.sort((a,b) => a.when.compareTo(b.when));
```

first declares `transactions` to have type `dynamic`.
Then you call `sort` on that with an argument which is inferred to have type `dynamic Function(dynamic, dynamic)` (because there is no clue available to say otherwise in the type of `transactions`).

However, the actual run-time type of `transactions` is `List<Transaction>`, and that requires a function argument of type `int Function(Transaction, Transaction)`. The type `dynamic Function(dynamic, dynamic)` is not a sub-type of `int Function(Transaction, Transaction)` (the return type has to be a subtype of `int` for that to be the case) so you get a run-time error.

If you change `transactions` to have type `List<Transaction>`, then the type inference will have a clue when it gets to the function literal. It will infer that `(a, b) => a.when.compareTo(b.when)` *in a context expecting `int Function(Transaction, Transaction)`* will have that type.

Even if you just change `transactions` to `List<dynamic>`, it will still work, it will just make `a.when.compareTo(b.when)` be dynamic invocations.