# Not able to assign a `List` to extended List in Dart

Tags: dart

I need to extend `List` to be able to overload `[]` operator.

I tried all the approaches from here: [How do I extend a List in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247045/how-do-i-extend-a-list-in-dart). But all of them give me the same error `A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MyCustomList<int>'.` when I assign usual `List` to my extended CustomList:

```
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

class MyCustomList<E> extends DelegatingList<E> {
  final List<E> _l = [];
  List<E> get delegate => _l;
}

void main() {
  MyCustomList<int> l = []; // << error here
}
```

Is it possible to extend so that this error disappeared?

I know that I can change to:

```
MyCustomList<int> l = [] as MyCustomList<int>;
```

But I would like to avoid it because of it would require massive changes in my real code.

Comment: Even the casting solution will not work, because you're trying to cast an instance of a superclass to a subclass. The literal `<T>[]` always creates an instance of `List<T>`, which has no member `delegate`, and therefore cannot be casted to `MyCustomList<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're trying to assign a `List<int>` to a variable of type `MyCustomList<int>`.

You can create a constructor and initialize the private list `_l`.

```dart
class MyCustomList<E> extends DelegatingList<E> {
  MyCustomList(List<E> list) {
    _l.addAll(list);
  }

  final List<E> _l = [];

  List<E> get delegate => _l;
}

void main() {
  MyCustomList<int> l = MyCustomList([1, 2, 3]);
}
```

**Note**: seems the `[]` operator overload is for `accessing` and `assigning` value to an element and you can't use it for *instantiate list*.

```dart
@override
void operator []=(int index, E value) => _l[index] = value;

@override
E operator [](int index) => _l[index];
```