# How to calculate total sum of data which is double in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Suppose `${d.price}` has all the prices (which is a double) of items in the list. How can i calculate the total sum of price using `${d.price}`?

Comment: can you post the specific code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611678/13625305

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405348/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-sum-of-numbers-in-a-collection-list-in-dart/13611678#13611678 @Sameer Pradhan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cleanest way to get the sum of numbers in a collection/list in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405348/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-sum-of-numbers-in-a-collection-list-in-dart)

Comment: Yes thank you call

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fold` to calculate the sum
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611678/13625305)
for example :

```
void main() {
  List<int> prices = [10,20,30];
  int sum = prices.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c);
  print(sum);
}
```

Output

```
60
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  List<int> a=[10,20,30,40];
  int sum=0;
  a.forEach((e){
    sum+=e;
  });
  print(sum);
}
```

o/p:

`100`

Answer (score 1):

if `d.price` has all the prices then
an easy approach to calculate the sum is:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<d.price.length; i++) {
    sum += d.price[i];
}

print( sum );
```

**Updated Code**

if you want to show the result you can use Text Widget.

```
Text( sum.toString() )
```

Comment: where should i use the for loop? in setState?

Comment: It is hard for me to tell where should you use this code by not seeing your code. If you provide more details then maybe I can tell you. Thank you

Comment: its just that i have to show the total sum in a text form. any alternative for that?

Comment: you can use a text widget to show the result. I have updated the code. You can have a look to get an idea about it.

Comment: the whole function should be called inside a void?