# Calculate Total Sum of a List Dynamically in Flutter Function Issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code that should calculate total sum of a list:

```
int _counter = 0;

Future getTotal(item) async {
int counter = 0;

_totalPrice.add(int.parse(item));
_totalPrice.forEach((element) => counter += element);

print('LIST: $_totalPrice');
print('SUM: $counter');
return counter;
```

}

The **_counter** should be global variable, so I can use it in other functions, but I am getting this strange issue that almost squares after second click of function, here is the result after I click it twice, instead of adding 1 **item**, the **SUM** is larger:

[image]

As you can see, the result of the **SUM** should be 312, not 468, for  some reason it calculates it wrongly. I just need it to calculate correctly the sum of the list each time the function is invoked.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621386/10285344

Comment: I agree: Using a more functional style will help you avoid 'inexplicable' errors.
However, your linked answer is not correct, as it fails on empty lists. Use `fold()` instead.

Comment: So something like this? `sum = given_list.fold(0, (previous, current) => previous + current);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must convert **int types to string** then parse it to int, this is must safe way to parsing erverthing that can be parse to int.
other problem is that you define _counter and you must **reset it** in function, you wrongly just define it again!

```
getTotal(item){
_counter = 0;
_totalPrice.add(int.parse(item.toString()));
_totalPrice.forEach((element) => _counter += element);

print('LIST: $_totalPrice');
print('SUM: $_counter');
return _counter;
```

}

Comment: This is okay answer, but not what I'm looking for exactly. The thing is recalling the _counter doesn't really work since I need the global one.

Comment: you must setState in this function at the end before return and it will work, but the best way is using global state manajment like GetX