# How to identify the List is empty, to avoid the Bad state: No element for ListMixin.reduce

Tags: flutter, dart, reduce

I am trying to calculate set of values based on user selection. I am using the reduce method to calculate it.

Its checking for the respective values in the list and throws this error since there is no data in the list.

I am struck in how to resolve this, below i have attached the code.

```
  get products => _products;

  get productSubtotal => _products.entries
      .map((product) => product.key.price * product.value)
      .toList();


  get total => _products.entries
      .map((product) => product.key.price * product.value)
      .toList()
      .reduce((value, element) => value + element)
      .toStringAsFixed(2);
}
```

below i have attached the error message.

```
Bad state: No element

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Obx Obx:file:///Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/workspace/purple_star/lib/widgets/cart_total_value.dart:14:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ListMixin.reduce (dart:collection/list.dart:222:22)
#1      CartController.total (package:purple_star/screens/cart/cart_controller.dart:40:8)
#2      CartTotalWidget.totalController (package:purple_star/widgets/cart_total_value.dart:34:19)
#3      CartTotalWidget.build.<anonymous closure> (package:purple_star/widgets/cart_total_value.dart:27:15)
#4      Obx.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:70:28)
#5      RxInterface.notifyChildren (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_interface.dart:26:27)
#6      _ObxState.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:54:19)
#7      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4782:27)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error indicates the `List` is empty. If you read the documentation for `reduce` it says "The iterable must have at least one element. If it has only one element, that element is returned.": https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-collection/ListMixin/reduce.html

Comment: Hi @julemand101 i found the issue and i dont know how to implement it. can you help me on this.

Comment: You can update your question to involve your problem so people can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that you overcomplicated the problem. What you should be asking is how to sum a list of numbers.

The answer is `sum` extension method from `IterableExtension`

Note that this method is specialized for `List<num>`, `List<int>` and `List<double>`,  it will return correct result type

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List<num> nums1 = [1, 2, 3.0];
var s1 = nums1.sum;  // s1 is inferred to num

List<double> nums2 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
var s2 = nums2.sum;  // s2 is inferred to double

List<int> nums3 = [1, 2, 3];
var s3 = nums3.sum;  // s3 is inferred to int
```

As an additional benefit you can call sum directly on an Iterable, without convering it to list:

```dart
var nums = [1, 2, 3.0];
var sumOfSquares = nums.map((x) => x * x).sum;
print(sumOfSquares);
```

See [What is the cleanest way to get the sum of numbers in a collection/list in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405348/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-sum-of-numbers-in-a-collection-list-in-dart)

To answer your original question:

You were probably looking for the [`fold<T>`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-collection/ListMixin/fold.html) method

```dart
T fold<T>(
   T initialValue,
   T combine(T previousValue, E element)
)
```

Contrary to reduce, `fold` allows you to specify initial element - empty list is no longer a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, it helped me.