# I want to calculate each number from the array in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array in the flutter

```
 final list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I want to loop through the array to calculate the sum of all the items in the array,how i can?

Comment: Calculate each number how?

Comment: I want result 15 using loop

Comment: You can just use a reducer or map to calculate it.

Comment: can you give me an example plz?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cleanest way to get the sum of numbers in a collection/list in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405348/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-sum-of-numbers-in-a-collection-list-in-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 final list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

 final result = list.reduce((sum, element){
 return sum + element;
 });
```

Comment: Anytime! Thats what SO is for! 

Answer (score 1):

This could do it

```
final sum = list.fold<int>(0, (previousValue, number) => previousValue + number);
```