# Addition of multiple student result assessment score in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a response from an API  that looks like this snippet below, i would like to add the values (student scores over a period of time) and display the total value in the text widget on the UI

```
data : [
{
score : 10
}

{
score: 34
}

{
score: 45
}
]
```

Comment: Are you using any model class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cleanest way to get the sum of numbers in a collection/list in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405348/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-sum-of-numbers-in-a-collection-list-in-dart)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes i am using model class

Comment: try comment/answer might solve your issue

Comment: List<Result>? results;
class Result {
  Result({
    this.id,
    this.assessments,
  });

 String? id;
  List<Assessment>? assessments;
}

class Assessment {
  Assessment({
    this.id,
    this.score,
  });
  String? id;
  int? score;
  
}

@YeasinSheikh

Comment: are you able to fetch result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop to add all values like the example

```
void main() {

  List data = [
    {"score": 10},
    {"score": 34},
    {"score": 45}
  ];

  int totalScore = 0;

  data.forEach((value) {
    totalScore += value['score'] as int;
  });

  print(totalScore); // Output 89
}
```

**Output:** 89

Answer (score 0):

As for the `List<Result>? results;` you can fold the `assessments`

```dart
 final result = Result(assessments: [
    Assessment(id: "1", score: 10),
    Assessment(id: "2", score: 34)
  ]);

  int total = result.assessments?.fold(0,
          (previousValue, element) => (element.score ?? 0) + previousValue!) ??
      0;

  print(total);
```