# Recursive function to calculate 25% of the sum of what is returned before

Tags: dart

I'd like to write a recursive function that returns a double and takes an int as input.

> If input == 1, return 1.
> If input == 2 the function must return 1.25 (the sum of what was previously returned, multiplied by 1.25)
> If input == 3 the function must return the sum of input = 2 and input = 1, multiplied by 1.25, therefore (1 + 1.25) * 1.25 = 2.8126
> If input == 4 the output must be (1 + 1.25 + 2.8126) * 1.25 = 6.32825
>
> etc etc

My attempt:

```
double _calc(int index) {
    if (index == 1) return 1;
    double tot = 0;
    tot += _calc(index -1);
    return tot * 1.25;
}
```

But the result is not what I expected.

I can achieve the correct result with a non recursive function:

```
double _calc(int index) {
    if (index == 1) return 1;
    if (index == 2) return 1.25;
    var tmp = [for(var i=0; i<index; i+=1) 0.0];
    tmp[0] = 1;
    tmp[1] = 1.25;
    for (int i=2; i<index; i++) {
        for (int j=i; j>=0; j--) {
            tmp[i] += tmp[j];
        }
        tmp[i] = tmp[i] * 1.25;
    }
    return tmp[index-1];
}
```

If it's possible, I'd like to get the correct result with a recursive function

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use StackOverflow to cheat on your homework or employer pre-screening. :(

Comment: Kind @RandalSchwartz
this is not a school assignment, but a personal doubt of mine. I finished my studies 10 years ago and am happily working for a company that I have no intention of leaving any time soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your recursive function only handles the output from the prior step; directly multiplying by 1.25

But your definition of the function must handle output from **all** previous steps. (sum them together), before multiplying by 1.25.

To do the "summing" of previous steps I added a `for` loop.  Please note this function is **inefficient** as OP commented on my answer(like how a [bad recursive Fibonacci is inefficient, described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence#comment13364404_8965006)):

```
  double _calc_bad(int index) {
    if (index == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    double tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      tot += _calc_bad(i);
    }
    return tot * 1.25;
  }
```

---

If you want to try a **more efficient** recursive function, you can use a technique [described in Data Structures and Algorithms in Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118290275)  ([direct PDF link here; see page 189](http://xpzhang.me/teach/DS19_Fall/book.pdf#page=189)) which creates a `good_fibonacci` instead of a `bad_fibonacci` by **remembering the previous call results**

```
  // recursive function returns more information for next call
  (double, List) _calc_cache(int index) {
    if (index == 1) {
      return (1, []);
    } else {
      var (prev, list_of_prev) = _calc_cache(index - 1);
      list_of_prev.add(prev);
      // sum using https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611678/1175496
      return (1.25 * list_of_prev.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c), list_of_prev);
    }
  }

  double _calc_good(int index) {
    var (result, l) = _calc_cache(index);
    return result;
  }
```

The technique here is similar to [@lrn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76605299/1175496) which caches the previous results in a global List object `_fCache`. I don't use a global variable; I return the variable inside the recursive function, which requires a different function signature. I made `_calc_cache()`, which returns a [`record`](https://dart.dev/language/records) of the result, and the list of previous results. You can destructure the record to return **just** the result if you want... (see the `_calc_good` function I made)

However, your simple use of for-loops, or @lrn's mathematical simplification of using `pow(2.25, ...)`, might both **more efficient** approaches!

Examples of output:

```
_calc_good(1)
> 1
_calc_good(2)
> 1.25
_calc_good(3)
> 2.8125
_calc_good(4)
> 6.328125
```

Comment: Thanks @Nate for the reply.
The proposed solution, in dart would be:
`double _calc(int index) { if (index == 1) { return 1; } double tot = 0; for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { tot += _calc(i); } return tot * 1.25;}`
And it works!! 
But this way the function is called so many times. eg inputs = 4, it's called 12 times.
I thought a solution could be found where the function was called a number of times equal to the number given in input (eg input = 4, function called 4 times)

Comment: Hi @ominofelice, yes I see what you mean. Similar to the way [recursive Fibonacci is inefficient, O(2^n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence#comment13364404_8965006), my answer is even worse. [lrn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76605299/1175496) avoids this by caching the results inside `_fCache`; I'll update my answer to use a similar approach as suggested in [Data Structures and Algorithms in Python](https://www.amazon.com/Structures-Algorithms-Python-Michael-Goodrich/dp/1118290275) -- but the function would have a different signature...

Comment: OK I added a dart function that shouldn't result in such a large number of calls. But I think @lrm's solution of using pow(2.25, index-2)*1.25 is clever!

Answer (score 1):

The most direct implementation would be:

```dart
import "dart:math" show pow;
double f(int index) {
  if (index < 1) throw ArgumentError.value(index, "index", "Must be >= 1");
  if (index == 1) return 1;
  return pow(2.25, index - 2) * 1.25;
}
```

(You can prove that it gives the correct value of all `index` >= 2 by induction, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. )

If you want to compute it using a recursive function, this is the kind of calculation which really benefits from caching.

```dart
List<double> _fCache = [0.0, 1.0];
double f(int index) {
  if (index < 1) throw ArgumentError.value(index, "index", "Must be >= 1");
  if (index < _fCache.length) return _fCache[index];
  double result = 0.0;
  for (var i = 1; i < index; i++) result += f(i);
  result *= 1.25;
  assert(_fCache.length == index);
  _fCache.add(result);
  return result;
}
```